# Distinguish Intent coming from an IntentChooser

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm having serious problems getting a picture coming from an IntentChooser. It lets you choose between getting a picture from the camera or your drive:

```
Intent pickIntent = new Intent();
pickIntent.setType("image/*");
pickIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

boolean cameraAvailable = isCameraAvailable(this);

String pickTitle = cameraAvailable? "Select or take a new Picture" : "Select a Picture";
Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(pickIntent, pickTitle);
if(cameraAvailable)
{

    Intent takePhotoIntent = new     Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    chooserIntent.putExtra
    (
      Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, 
      new Intent[] { takePhotoIntent }
    );
}
startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, GET_PICTURE);
```

Where `isCameraAvailable(Context context)` checks if there is a camera waiting in the system.

The problem is that, when in `onActivityResult`, both intents (take picture or get picture from gallery) have, of course, the same `requestCode`, so I have to make a difference in another way. I've found out that the intent coming from the camera, has an action of `inline-data`, while the other just has no action at all:

```
if(intent.getAction() == "inline-data")
{
    bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getExtras().get("data");
}
else
{
    InputStream stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(
        intent.getData());
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
    stream.close();
}
```

Now, the problem comes that I'm not pretty sure this is the best solution to differentiate, and I was thinking if there is a way to check the complete action (`MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` or `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT`) or another one. Thanks in advance.

**Tiny edit**: In my case, which consists in grabbing a picture from anywhere or create it from scratch, the example just works, but for the sake of improving my code (and finding a more generic answer) I'll leave it open to suggestions.